# Iterate through dictionary returns None even the value was found

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to get the values from `data` but the function below always give me None. I included the `print` inside the loop so that I could actually see that the condition is correct, not sure why its returning None instead. But the value being printed is correct.

```
data = { 
    'test1': { 
        'test1.1': { 
            'a': 'a', 
            'b': 'b' 
        } 
    }, 
    'test2': { 
        'test2.1': { 
            'test2.2': { 
                'c': 'c', 
                'd': 'd' 
            } 
        }, 
        'test_list': [1,2,3] 
    } 
}

def get_dict(key, dict_data): 
    for k, v in dict_data.items(): 
        if k == key and isinstance(v, dict): 
            print(v) 
            return v 
        else: 
            if isinstance(v, dict): 
                return get_dict(key, v) # <-- added return, same result
```

`get_dict('test1', data)` returns `OK`

`get_dict('test1.1', data)` returns `None` but shoud have `{'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}`

`get_dict('test2', data)` returns `OK`

`get_dict('test2.1', data)` returns `None` but should return `{'test2.2': {'c': 'c', 'd': 'd'}}`

Comment: Works fine for me. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: You have a missing `return` in the last line: `return get_dict(key, v)`. And possibly another missing `return` for the missing `else` branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you never get to the second key because both paths return in your code and you can never get more than one iteration in the loop. You don't need to loop over the dict items. Just try to access the key. If it's not there loop over the values and recurse, returning the first thing you find:

```
data = { 
    'test1': { 
        'test1.1': { 
            'a': 'a', 
            'b': 'b' 
        } 
    }, 
    'test2': { 
        'test2.1': { 
            'test2.2': { 
                'c': 'c', 
                'd': 'd' 
            } 
        }, 
        'test_list': [1,2,3] 
    } 
}

def get_dict(key, dict_data):
    if not isinstance(dict_data, dict):
        return
    try:
        return dict_data[key]   
    except KeyError:
        for v in dict_data.values():
            found = get_dict(key, v)
            if found:
                return found


get_dict('test2.2', data)
# {'c': 'c', 'd': 'd'}

get_dict('test2.1', data)
# {'test2.2': {'c': 'c', 'd': 'd'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should continue to look into other dicts as well.

The code below assumes no hierarchy:

```py
def get_dict(key, dict_data): 
    for k, v in dict_data.items(): 
        if k == key and isinstance(v, dict): 
            return v 
        elif isinstance(v, dict): 
            ret = get_dict(key, v)
            if ret is not None:
                return ret
    return None
```